# AWS CloudFront - Importing a parameter as a "global" parameter across cloudfront stacks

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, import, aws-cloudformation

I would like to export a value from a stack that I am running and then import it into another stack as sorta a "global" parameter, so that I can manipulate it and use it for an S3 bucket name. I already know that I can accomplish importing the value individually on a line within a resource using something like:

{ "Fn::ImportValue" : { "Fn::Sub" : "${StackName}-ParameterName" } }

But is there a way to import it into my Parameters section?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

> But is there a way to import it into my Parameters section?

There is no such option. The closest you could get would be to save your global values in **SSM Parameter Store** and use [dynamic references](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/dynamic-references.html) in CloudFormation as `Default` values in your `Parameters`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve this

1. Use [SSM Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html#aws-ssm-parameter-types), store the value from the source stack to SSM parameter store

   ```
        BasicParameter:
        Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter
        Properties:
        Name: AvailabilityZone
        Type: String
        Value:
            Ref: AvailabilityZone
   ```

and then reference the value directly into the parameters section like below:

```
    ---
    AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
    Parameters:
    ...
    AvailabilityZone:
        Description: Amazon EC2 instance Availablity Zone
        Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>
        Default: AvailabilityZone
    Mappings: {}
    Conditions: {}
    Resources:
    myinstance:
        Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
        Properties:
        AvailabilityZone:
            Ref: AvailabilityZone
            ...
```

The full example can be found [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-systems-manager-parameter/#:%7E:text=An%20SSM%20parameter%20stores%20a,AWS%20Systems%20Manager%20Parameter%20Store.)

2. You consume the output from the source stack and pass them to the destination stack while launching the stack.

Source stack output configured

```
    Outputs:
    InstanceID:
        Description: The Instance ID
        Value: !Ref EC2Instance
```

Consumer them in the destination stack:

```
        aws \
        --region us-east-1 \
        cloudformation deploy \
        --template-file cfn.yml \
        --stack-name mystack \
        --no-fail-on-empty-changeset \
                    --tags Application=awesomeapp \
        --parameter-overrides \
                                    "Somevar=OUTUT_FROM_SOURCE_STACK"
```